# top down car when making a turn the sprite separates to the body

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-physics

I made a top down car game for android using libGdx the body of the car i used came from another app that I sample. The problem is when im making a turn, the sprite separates from the body of the car:

Here is the image, i was talking about the white car in the image:
[image]

Comment: i finally solved the problem by correcting the origin of the sprite relative to "body" as @juan javier Cassani stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the origin of the sprite to center with:

```
setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() /2f, sprite.getHeight() /2f);
```

This will make rotations and scalings use that point instead of default (0, 0)